# Error while trying to target in arules (data is in the format of web addresses)

Tags: r, arules

I've successfully imported my data into R as transactions, but when I try targeting a specific website, I get this error:

Error in asMethod(object) : FACEBOOK.COM is an unknown item label

Is there any reason why this could be happening? Here is a snippet of code:

```
target.conf80 = apriori(trans,
parameter = list(supp=.002,conf=.8),
appearance = list(default="lhs",rhs = "FACEBOOK.COM"),
control = list(verbose = F))
target.conf80 = sort(target.conf80,decreasing=TRUE,by="confidence")
inspect(target.conf80[1:10])
```

Thanks!

Here is what the transactions look like:

```
1 {V1=Google,                                  
   V2=Google Web Search,                       
   V3=FACEBOOK.COM}                           1
2 {V1=FACEBOOK.COM,                            
   V2=MCAFEE.COM,                              
   V3=7EER.NET,                                
   V4=Google}                                 2
3 {V1=MCAFEE.COM,
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you read/convert the data to transactions. The transactions should look like:

```
1 {Google,                                  
   Google Web Search,                       
   FACEBOOK.COM}                           1
2 {FACEBOOK.COM,                            
   MCAFEE.COM,                              
   7EER.NET,                                
   Google}                                 2
 3 {MCAFEE.COM,
    ...
```

Without the V1, V2, etc. In your transactions `V1=Google` and `V4=Google` are different items.

Comment: How can you get rid of `V1, V2, V3, ...`? You get that when you run this code... `data <- as(data, 'transactions')` and your data is a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

### Error `as(data, 'transactions')` From Data Frames

I'm assuming that the dataset was transformed as follow...`data <- as(data, 'transactions')`. If you run that code without performing some manipulations with your data you will get those `V1, V2, ...`.

### Cleaning Data Before Transactions

I want to include how to manipulate the data to be ready for `read.transctions()`. After importing your data into R you want to convert your dataframe to a matrix like so... `d.matrix <- as.matrix(df)`, the you want to eliminate any headers if happened that you do have headers; `colnames(d.matrix) <- NULL`. Now you don't have headers. After that you want to....

```
write.table(x = d.matrix, 
      file = 'clean_data.csv',
      sep = ',',
      col.names = FALSE, 
      row.names = FALSE)
```

Finally, you want to import the data as transaction like so...

```
data <- read.transactions('clean_data.csv',
                           format = 'basket',
                           sep = ',',
                           rm.duplicates = TRUE)
```

Now you have a dataset with no `V1, V2, V3, ...` and no row ID's